# Mule - How can I use set-session-variable in http:listener?

Tags: mule, session-variables, mule-studio, httplistener, mule-component

I have a `composite-source` consist of two `http:listener` in Mule;

I want to set a variable based on each of the listeners after receive requests from these listeners ;

but this error occurs while deploys in mule 3.6.0:

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'set-session-variable'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":response-builder, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":error-response-builder}' is expected.
```

What should I do??

Here is my code:

```
<composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
  <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration_Source1"
    path="/" doc:name="HTTP">
        <set-session-variable doc:name="Session Variable" value="#[x]" variableName="x" />
  </http:listener>
  <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration_Source2"
                path="/" doc:name="HTTP">
        <set-session-variable doc:name="Session Variable" value="#[y]" variableName="x" />
  </http:listener>
</composite-source>
```

P.S. I have done it with `http:inbound-endpoint`

Comment: OOC does it work if you have a single `http:listener` not in a `composite-source`?

Comment: No, the error still occurs, is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's illegal to put a `set-session-variable` there: the Mule schema does not allow it.

The reason is that `http:listener` is not a regular `endpoint`, like `http:inbound-endpoint` is, thus doesn't support this kind of nesting, like all other endpoints do.

This is unfortunate and hopefully something that will get fixed eventually. In the meantime, you need to find another way to discriminate requests coming between these two listeners.

For this I recommend you check all the inbound message properties they created, looking for a differentiator. I'm expecting a `MULE_` property to be usable here but you'll have to check in your particular context, with the specific `HTTP_Listener` configurations you are using.

Comment: Thank you, your comments are always helpful. but In this case I want to set other variables based on request path in order to route the requests, etc... , So set 'MULE_' properties and differentiate them doesn't resolve the issue here. Furthermore I think set and check properties may affect the performance in comparison with 'set-session-variable'.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to set `MULE_` properties but to read them to find a discriminant in them: you'd be free to compute a custom value based on this discriminant, and `set-session-variable` it. I do think reading/setting properties would have a significant performance impact, especially compared to the time that will be spent doing I/O. Don't decide against an approach based on potential perf issues: try load testing it to see the reality of it.